# Azure Cloud Service Project opens two Browser Windows on Start when Debugging

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

I have a VS2013 (Update 3) Solution with one Azure Cloud Service Project that has one Web Role / ASP.Net Project and the later has 'Don't open a page.' selected underneath its Propers > Web tabcard, but whenever I start the Azure CS .ccproj for debugging (the later is set as startup project), two (not one) browser Windows are opened each time.

Does anyone know where I can disable this or at least set it to one window only? It's running with Azure SDK 2.4, I am using IIS Express & (Azure) Emulator Express.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right click on your `Web Role` --> `Properties` --> `Startup Action` --> Please uncheck one of the boxes under `Launch browser for`

[image]

Comment: Oh my, I didn't look there. It works - Thanks @gaurav-mantri !

Comment: Does anyone else find that this setting does not persist consistently?

Comment: Did you upgrade the SDK? I have seen that happening when I upgrade the SDK.